# How to access a user defined QObject that is instantiated in another thread in python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qml

I've never had this issue using c++, but recently i've been using QML/PyQt5/Python and i've run across the following error:

```bash
QQmlEngine: Illegal attempt to connect to MyClass(0x1fd42731e50) that is in a different thread than the QML engine QQmlApplicationEngine(0x1fd41562f70.
```

I have a worker thread that creates a **QObject** that i've defined. That is spawned by a controller thread which is set as a context property.

Here is an M.R.E.:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 600
    title: "Clock"


    Text {
        id: backend_data
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: backend.my_class.value.toString()
    }
}
```

```py
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtProperty, QThread, QTimer, pyqtSlot
import sys
import copy

class MyClass(QObject):

    value_changed = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, value):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self._value = value

    @pyqtProperty(int, notify=value_changed)
    def value(self):
        return self._value

class Worker(QObject):

    my_class_signal = pyqtSignal(QObject)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QObject.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._i = 0
        self.timer=QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.send_my_class)
        self.timer.start(1000)
        self._my_class = MyClass(0) 

    @pyqtSlot()
    def send_my_class(self):
        self._i += 1
        self._my_class = MyClass(self._i)
        self.my_class_signal.emit(self._my_class)

class Backend(QObject):

    my_class_changed = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QObject.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._my_class = MyClass(0)
        self._thread = QThread()
        self._worker = Worker() 
        self._worker.moveToThread(self._thread)
        self._worker.my_class_signal.connect(self.receive_my_class)
        self._thread.start()

    @pyqtSlot(QObject)
    def receive_my_class(self, myclass):
        self._my_class = myclass
        self.my_class_changed.emit()

    @pyqtProperty(QObject, notify=my_class_changed)
    def my_class(self):
        return self._my_class

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    backend = Backend()
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty('backend', backend)
    engine.load('./example.qml')
    if len(engine.rootObjects()) > 0:
        sys.exit(app.exec())
```

What should i be doing differently?

Comment: Qt cannot send an instance of QObject across threads, because the QObject class isn't copyable. Whenever PyQt encounters such objects, it will send a pointer instead (which you can confirm by printing the id in each thread). Passing pointers between threads in this way is asking for trouble. Neither Qt nor PyQt will stop you doing it - but if anything goes wrong, *it's your fault*. If you want code like this to work safely, you should instead send whatever data is needed to reconstruct the object in the receiving thread (and this data must be pickleable for PyQt to serialise it properly).

Answer (score 0):

python has an feature called GIL (global interpreter lock) which makes sure that only 1 instance of CPython (the python interpreter) can exists at a time. even if you're using a thread, python just transfers the CPython instance between threads, so there's still only 1 interpreter running. Personally, i like to use another language (like rust or c++) to handle the threads, and place those thread handles in some sort of a class or function. However, if you must use only PyQt5, then i know a lot of people that like to just use [AsyncIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) (which PyQt5 works far better with than with threads). and if you **really** want to use threads, then use [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html).

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question, most importantly because the issue is not *directly* related to the GIL: that's fundamentally a symptom of the issue, and "only 1 instance of [the python interpreter] can exist at any time" is also an imprecise description, as Python certainly doesn't "transfer the CPython instance between threads" (it *may* be interpreted like that, but that description is inaccurate and misleading). Also, almost any Qt class is not thread-safe unless it is explicitly declared (including access to the object functions).